# Multiple Navigation Controllers with Back Buttons in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm making an application that has:

Navigation Controller -> View Controller -> Navigation Controller -> View Controller -> Navigation Controller -> View Controller.

This is making it so that there's no back button on the second view controller, only the third one, and I can't get it to appear. I'm fairly new to iOS and simply want to have a path of view controllers that the user can navigate down and back. Is there a way to add the back button to the second view controller's nav bar? Is there a better way to do this? Is it problematic to just create buttons at the top of views that perform segues?

I found some Objective-C solutions but couldn't find anything in Swift. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Why do you have multiple navigation controllers?  Just use one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove all the navigation controllers except the first one.Your app must be like this..

> Navigation Controller -> View Controller -> View Controller -> View
>   Controller.

Call segue to move to the other controller .. Just dismiss your controller if you have modally showed them on back button pressed or pop them from

> navigationController

if you have pushed them.
Now for Back, you can do it in multiple ways. One of them is, add a view on the top of your controller, add a button on it and implement an action when someone taped it..
I hope you will got that ...